# Access and change a value created with `define`

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm making a game, and I have this:

```
(define b "black piece") (define w "white piece")

(define (board)
 (lambda (matrix) 
   (list ((b w b w b w b w) 
          (w b w b w b w b) 
          (b w b w b w b w) 
          (w b w b w b w b) 
          (b w b w b w b w) 
          (w b w b w b w b) 
          (b w b w b w b w) 
          (w b w b w b w b)))))
```

`board` makes a list with 8 lines and 8 columns of black and white pieces.

How do I access and change elements of the board?  How do I do the procedure matrix with recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first a few notes:
`(define f (lambda (x) l ))`
is the same as
`(define (f x) l ))`
You however are combining them with
`(define (board) (lambda (matrix) l ))`
which is the same as
`(define board (lambda () (lambda (matrix) l )))`

The distinction is important.  The first two I have listed bind f to a function that take one parameter and return l.  I'm guessing this is what you want to do.  In the second two, you're binding board to a function that takes no parameters and returns a function that takes 1 parameter, matrix, (which it doesn't seem to do anything with), and returns a l.

second issue, `(list ((b w....) ...))` isn't going to work because it will try to evaluate `(b w ...)`.  you need to have list in the function application position for each row of your board like so `(list (list b w ...) (list w b ...) ...)` in order for you code to even compile.

On to your question.  [link-ref](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list-ref#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29) is included in racket/base and is used for referencing elements in a list when you know the index into the list.
(list-ref 2 (list 'a 'b 'c 'd))
will return 'c.  The index starts at 0.  Since you have a list of lists, you will need to apply list-ref twice to retrieve a 'b or 'w.

As for changing it, well, you can't.  As of r6rs, pairs (which make up lists) are immutable.  The recommended way of doing things when possible is to return a new list with your change.  you can use this somewhat inefficient version of `list-set` which returns a copy of the list with your new value at an index.

```
(define (list-set lis idx val)
  (map (lambda (e i)
    (if (= i idx) val e))  
    lis  
    (iota (length lis))))
```

In this case however, I would recommend switching to a different data structure more appropriate to the task at hand since you probably want O(1) access to the elements in the board.  Look into [vectors](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) which behave much like lists but are used for constant lookups and updates.  there is a built in `vector-ref` and `vector-set!` operations, which you should use instead of my above function.

Incase this is part of a larger problem and you're already using lists everywhere, you can use the `vector->list` and `list->vector` functions to go back and forth.  Also, you can use [mutable lists](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html) but don't.

Better still is the multidimensional array library offered in [srfi/25](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-25/srfi-25.html), but that might be more complicated that you want to get.

The second part of your question was how to construct the board recursively.  Well, here's a version using map.

```
(require (lib "1.ss" "srfi"))
(define (board)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (map (lambda (y)
                (if (odd? (+ x y)) b w))
              (iota 8)))
       (iota 8)))
```

and here's a recursive version

```
(define (board)
  (letrec ((board-helper
            (lambda (x)
          (if (eq? x 8) '()
          (cons (row-helper x 0) (board-helper (+ 1 x))))))
       (row-helper
        (lambda (x y)
          (if (eq? y 8) '()
          (cons (if (odd? (+ x y)) b w) (row-helper x (+ 1 y)))))))
    (board-helper 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks! That was just what i needed, the two versions, the one using map is more efficient? I'm trying to make a konane game.... this was the board, and next I'll make an automatic computer player. I don't have many knowleage about scheme, so it's kind of dificult. Well, you helped-me a lot, mainly to understand the way to get to the problem. Thanks again and happy new year!